# How to get email notification for still unused tags on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I am creating a [program](https://github.com/le-moulin-studio/forest) which is expected to push a trend's popularity forward ('f2f' which stands for "friend-to-friend', a sub category of 'p2p'). I wish to get notifications for  this tag on Overflow, but the option of subscribing to it doesn't appear on the Stack Overflow website.

Could it be that I have to use the tag in a question first, then I can subscribe to it?

PS: If I am right, then I think I created the first question ever which answers itself and is the solution of itself in the whole history of Stack Overflow. Yeah !! ^_^

PPS: If seems that I need more reputation to create the tag 'f2f'. I hope someone with the right privilege could help me to create it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand now, I need to get a reputation of 1500. **Then** I am allowed to create a tag and **then** I can technically subscribe to it.

I hoped to be able to subscribe to it before it was created (which IMHO makes sense), but maybe I am asking too much from the Stack Exchange system.

Comment: You can't create a tag without adding it to at least one question. You'll need at least one (good) question related to your software for that to work.

Comment: @Mat: I can't add it to a question without it to be created first. Users need 1500 of reputation in order to create a tag.

Comment: Yes, what I'm saying is that even once you get 1.5k rep, the only way to create a new tag is by tagging a question. If there already _are_ questions about f2f on SO, post a link here and someone could create the tag for you.

Comment: Thanks, I will do so on my next f2f question.